# IDirectDrawSurface7::BltFast Rect vs. X & Y Co-ords

Tags: c++, directx

This DirectX 7 function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg426183(v=vs.85).aspx

The parameters include an LPRECT as well as X and Y co-ordinates. My confusion lies in which take priority; the top left co-ordinate of the rectangle, or the X & Y co-ordinates.

Maybe I'm being a total idiot and they serve different purposes, but I don't understand how. Please be patient with me; I'm certainly not as experienced as 99% of you guys, but I'm getting there slowly.

Thanks.

Comment: Damn, I think I've been a complete moron. 
The rect is the part of the image that you want to render, right? And the x and y co-ordinates are where you want to render to?

Sorry for being such a fool. I think that I knew this anyway, and simply forgot briefly.

Comment: great can you provide then an answer to your question. or remove it altogether

Comment: I can't, I have to wait.

Comment: What the hell is the point in the whole "You can't answer your own question for 8 hours" and "You can't accept your own answer for a day" thing about? It's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a moronic question.
The rect is the part of the image that you want to render, and the x and y co-ordinates are where you want to render to. The source rectangle, and the destination co-ordinates.

Sorry for being such a fool.